# Is there a difference between a Flash CC and Flash CS 6 compiled Air app?

Tags: air, packaging, flash-cs6, flash-cc

I'm currently creating my Adobe Air iOS and Android apps with Flash CS 6.
Do I need to upgrade to meet the new iOS 8 and Android requirements? (64bit) 
(Is there a difference between apps that get published with Flash CS 6 and Flash CC?)

Comment: I think there's no difference.  You need to keep your Air SDK up to date.  That's what you update regularly to meet updates in IOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware the only difference could be if CS6 allows you to package the app with faster packaging enabled, (a checkbox underneath the drop down menu where you specify the target format, AdHoc, App Store etc.) as this is now a requirement if you use ANE's or are planning on publishing your app on the app store.